# SVN gives conflicts without real differences

Tags: svn, conflict

After a merge of branches, I get a lot of conflicts like these:

```
<<<<<<< .working

       return $sql;
=======

       return $sql;
>>>>>>> .merge-right.r37555
```

...where I can not see real differences. Why is SVN giving me these?

Comment: Are you sure the differences aren't additional spaces (indentation)?  I get that every so often after I edit something and the IDE reformats the code on me.

Comment: What was the problem exactly? IDE converting tabs to spaces or Line Endings? And thanks for accepting. ;)

Comment: @sjas: I was manually going through all the conflicts after a merge in Netbeans...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your whitespaces and line endings. (Tab vs. Space, CRLF vs. LF)

You could do that with vim, `:se list` is used to display all characters. `:se nolist` turns it off again.